# Returning address of local variable or temporary when using C++0x decltype return value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++11, type-inference

**Edit:**

This is indeed a bug in the compiler, I've opened a [defect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/573330/bad-code-generated-for-function-using-a-decltype-return-value?wa=wsignin1.0#details) and got the following response.

> Hello Motti,
>   Thank you for submitting this issue. As noted in the stackoverflow posting, this is a bug in our decltype implementation. Unfortunately, we cannot fix this bug in the next release of Visual Studio since the code is relatively uncommon, and we are particularly resource constrained.

*Original question follows*

---

I'm playing around with the C++0x features of VS10 and I ran into the following problem.

```
std::map<int, int> map()
{
    return std::map<int, int>();
}

template <class F>
auto call(F f) -> decltype(f())
{       
    auto ret = f();
    return ret;
}

void check() 
{
    auto m = call(map); 
}
```

I get the following warning:

> warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

However when I change the prototype of `call` to be the old style:

```
std::map<int, int> call(F f)
```

It's fine, it's also OK when `call` is not a template function (even when using deduced return types).

If I look at the type of `ret` it's `std::map<int, int>` (no references or pointers).

Is this a bug in VS10 or am I missing something.

Comment: Will the debugger tell you what type `auto ret` resolves to? I know there are some differences between the way `auto` and `decltype` behave, but i have no idea if that's causing the problem...

Comment: FWIW, Comeau barks at the `auto` preceding `call()`. (Of course, I have no idea who is right here...)

Comment: @Motti: Yes, although I don't know the Comeau's level of C++1x support. [Try it yourself.](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/)

Comment: FWIW, `g++ -std=c++0x` doesn't seem to mind this code.

Comment: @sbi: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/439features.html doesn't look like they're doing `decltype` yet.

Comment: @Cogwheel: Their online compiler has 4.3.10.1 and I was using that. Unfortunately, Greg's website has always been a mess, and I got lost trying to find out whether they have `decltype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`call(map);` implicitly converts map to a function pointer, to make the function:

```
auto call( std::map<int,int>(*f)() ) -> decltype(f())
```

It looks like VC10 isn't meeting the c++0x FCD for decltype, which says:

> The type denoted by decltype(e) is deﬁned as follows:
>
> - if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or a class member access [snip, it isn't]
> - otherwise, if e is a function call (5.2.2) or [snip], decltype(e) is the return type of the statically chosen function;
> - otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e;
> - otherwise, decltype(e) is the type of e.

5.2.2 makes it clear that calling through a function pointer is a "function call" so `decltype(f())` should be `std::map<int,int>`.  Instead, it's treating f() like an lvalue espression, with the result `std::map<int,int> &`.  The type of ret is being inferred correctly, but it's being cast into a reference by the return.

This bug doesn't show up when you use a function expression instead of a function pointer expression, `decltype(map())` correctly results in `std::map<int,int>`.